Why are only primal and dual attacks dealt with among the various attacks on LWE?
As we see in https://estimate-all-the-lwe-ntru-schemes.github.io/docs/, only dual and primal attacks are the most important attacks against LWE and NTRU schemes. On the other hand, many attacks such as DBDD, Arrora & Ge, MITM and so on exist to deal with lattice hard problems. My question is that out of all these attacks, why are only the two mentioned attacks addressed?

This is answered in the accompanying paper. I quote from page 4.

In this work, we restrict our attention to a subset of attacks on both
families of problems. For LWE, we restrict our attention to the uSVP
variant of the primal lattice attack as given in [BG14, ADPS16, AGVW17] and the dual lattice attack as given in [MR09 ,Alb17]. We disregard algebraic [AG11 , ACFP14] and combinatorial [AFFP14, GJS15, KF15, GJMS17]
attacks, since those algorithms are not competitive for the parameter sets
considered here in the sieving regime$^4$.
${}^4$ BKW-style algorithms do outperform BKZ in the enumeration regime for some
medium-sized parameter sets. However, similarly to BKZ in the sieving regime, BKW requires $2^{\Theta(n)}$ memory.

